What do the xenomorphs eat in "Alien" 1979?
In any of the movies/books about Alien are there any hints of what they eat?
Not humans, because they always use them as incubators (both when the face hugger uses them to incubate the egg and when the Queen does it).
p.s. While the "embryo" eats the host (as some species of Wasps do), once it bursts out of the host what does it eat?

Anything it bl**dy wants to!

@Paulie_D - Except broccoli. Everyone hates broccoli
